# Randomly pick index/shuffle in a map from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map that takes an array from my state and renders news articles. However, I want it to randomly render the news articles in different orders, either using the index from the map function or any other way. How to do that? My code:

```
  this.state.newsItems.map((item, i) => (this.renderSlide(item, i)))}
```

The array always come in the same order, how do I shuffle it?